# Supporting evidence i-130

Tags: usa, immigration

Before anything I'd like to thank all the help you have provided.

I'm about to file the i-130 for my husband and this is the supporting evidence we are sending.

- My birth certificate
- birth certificate of our firstborn who passed away 3 days after
  birth (translated)
- death certificate of our firstborn (translated)
- birth certificate of our daughter (translated)
- power of attorney my husband registered on my name to do various
  legal paperwork (translated)
- marriage certificate (translated)
- fiscal registry of the first apartment we bought (translated)
- registration of a company we started 12 years ago, still active
  (translated)
- 3 vehicle registration on my name with my married last name
  (translated)
- 43 photos of most of our 13 years together.

We never used joint accounts, as my husband always pays the biggest bills and I pay the groceries and smaller bills.
Do you suggest that we include the 3 affidavit letters? Do you suggest that I include anything else?

Thank you guys for your help, may god bless you all.